# Ray - Tensorflow - parallel processing issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

By following the article
https://towardsdatascience.com/modern-parallel-and-distributed-python-a-quick-tutorial-on-ray-99f8d70369b8
I'm trying to use Ray module for parallel processing of below tensorflow program
'''

```
import ray
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
ray.init()


graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  variable = tf.Variable(42, name='foo')
  initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  assign = variable.assign(13)
  
  

@ray.remote
class Simulator(object):
    def __init__(self):        
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
        
        
    def simulate(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
        self.sess.run(initialize)
        self.sess.run(assign)        
        return self.sess.run(variable)
    
# Create two actors.
simulators = [Simulator.remote() for _ in range(2)]

# Run two simulations in parallel.
results = ray.get([s.simulate.remote() for s in simulators])
print(results)
```

'''

but ended up with the below issues:

**TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects**

**TypeError: Could not serialize the actor class**

Can anyone please let me know if there is any issue in my approach.

I observed the same error (can't pickle _thread.RLock objects)even if I use multiprocessing module

Please find the versions I'm using:

python - 3.7.4

tensorflow - 2.0.0

ray - 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are creating some TF objects (e.g., `variable`, `initialize`, and `assign`) in your main script and then using them inside of the actor. This causes Ray to try to serialize the TF objects when it serializes the `Simulator` class definition (because these have to get passed from one process to another). TF objects are often not serializable. Instead, you could create the objects inside of the actor. For example

```py
import ray
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Simulator(object):
    def __init__(self):        
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        with self.graph.as_default():
          self.variable = tf.Variable(42, name='foo')
          self.initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
          self.assign = self.variable.assign(13)
        
    def simulate(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        self.sess.run(self.initialize)
        self.sess.run(self.assign)        
        return self.sess.run(self.variable)
    
# Create two actors.
simulators = [Simulator.remote() for _ in range(2)]

# Run two simulations in parallel.
results = ray.get([s.simulate.remote() for s in simulators])
print(results)
```